# Find earliest entry in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the following table of employees.

[image: employees]

It's fairly simple right? Clock in when you start, clock out for lunch, clock back in after lunch, clock out when you leave. But can someone please tell me what time these employees actually started? So for example how would you go about saying Tom was here at 6:51 AM and not at 12:23 PM?

For more reference, all entries look like this. They have at least 4 entries, (some one, no lunch).

How do I go about writing a formula that returns the start time?

I edited the table and added a helper column for the date. See below.

ANSWER:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6, $C$2:$C$7/((A11=$A$2:$A$7)*(B11=$B$2:$B$7)),1)
```

[image: with date]

Comment: Do you want just the IN and OUT times, or are you looking to calculate the hours worked between IN and OUT?

Comment: Hours worked is easy. It’s just a sumif of the employee name and date. I want the in time and technically there’s two in times. So how do I find the earliest time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the working hours are within the day, you can search for the smallest time. If there is a night shift over midnight, then there is a problem ...

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/($A$2:$A$5=A2)*(INT(B2)=INT($B$2:$B$5)))*($B$2:$B$5),1)
```

[image]

Comment: We have some employees that work night shift so they start one day and finish their shift the next day. This formula does work, but index match is easier. I was hoping for a method that won't require a sort.

Comment: Then post your formula as new answer and mark question as answered so it does not remain open.

Comment: It’s not an answer. I still need a formula that will find the earliest entry given a criteria without sorting. If I work it out I will post the answer.

Comment: I didn't understand - my formula doesn't need sorting. What is the problem with it?

Comment: Your formula doesn't work for night shift. Thanks for teaching me how to use aggregate tho.

Answer (score 0):

I've written down this formula for range E2:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A3,TRUNC(B2,0)-TRUNC(B3,0)=0),MIN(B2,B3),IF(AND(IFERROR(TRUNC(B2)-TRUNC(B1)=0,FALSE),E1=MIN(B2,B1)),"",B2))"
```

Since english is not my default language on Excel, i've just manually translated it. Anyway, just in case, here is the VBA code to paste it in range E2:

```
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-4]=R[1]C[-4],TRUNC(RC[-3],0)-TRUNC(R[1]C[-3],0)=0),MIN(RC[-3],R[1]C[-3]),IF(AND(IFERROR(TRUNC(RC[-3])-TRUNC(R[-1]C[-3])=0,FALSE),R[-1]C=MIN(RC[-3],R[-1]C[-3])),"""",RC[-3]))"
```

I've tried various configurations and it works for me. Only point: list must be sorted by Name and Clock In.

Comment: In order for your formula to work, the records must be sorted from oldest to newest. To be honest, even though your formula does work, an index match is easier.